# Find $438^{87493} \equiv ~? \pmod{11}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How to find the value of '?'
a mod m = b mod m , will this formula be used?
I am taking discrete maths course for CS. And this question is from one of its chapter

Comment: What is $438 (\mod 11)$?  And what is the order of $(\Bbb Z / 11 \Bbb Z)^*$?

Comment: 438 mod 11 would be 9 
And I don't know what you mean by order of (Z/11Z)

Comment: For us to be able to help you effectively, you need to provide more background.  Why is this problem of interest to you?  How have you tried to solve it?

Comment: I am taking discrete maths course for CS. And this question is from one of its chapter

Comment: Thanks.  How have you tried to solve it?  You should edit this information directly into your question, rather than using a comment.

Comment: Have you taken any classes that cover modulo arithmetic.  Fermat's Little Theorem basically is the first thing you should thing of.  ANd it should be the last and it gives you the answer immediately with no surprises.

Comment: There are two relationships,  a mod m = b mod m.  And gcd{a,m} = gcd {b,m}
Maybe either of these two can be used to find the value of b, but I don't understand how to apply them or how to solve for the power

Comment: @fleablood I have taken modulo arithmetic classes, but we haven't covered fermat's little theorem yet

Comment: Well what have you tried.  Do you know what $438\pmod {11}\equiv k \pmod{11}$ is?  Have you tried seeing what $k^2, k^3, k^4 \pmod {11}$ are and seeing if there is any pattern?

Comment: would k be 20 ? if we solve for 438 (mod 11) = k (mod 11)?

Comment: also i looked at fermet's little theorem. For that should the power be a prime number? but in this case the power is divisible by 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\text {gcd} (11,438) = 1.$ So by Euler's theorem $438^{10} \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$ So $438^{87490} \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$  Also $438 \equiv -2\ (\text {mod}\ 11) \implies 438^3 \equiv -8 \equiv 3\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$ Therefore $$438^{87493} \equiv 3\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$$

If you don't know Euler's theorem or Fermat's little theorem then observe from my above calculation that $438^3 \equiv 3\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$ So $438^6 \equiv 9 \equiv -2\ (\text {mod}\ 11) \implies 438^{30} \equiv (-2)^5 \equiv -32 \equiv 1 (\text {mod}\ 11).$

Observe that $87493 = 87480 + 13.$ Since $30 \mid 87480$ so $438^{87480} \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$ Since $438^6 \equiv -2\ (\text {mod}\ 11)$ so $438^{12} \equiv 4\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$ Again $438 \equiv -2\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$ So $438^{13} \equiv 438^{12} \cdot 438 \equiv 4 \cdot (-2) \equiv -8 \equiv 3\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$ Thus we get

$(1)$ $438^{87480} \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$

$(2)$ $438^{13} \equiv 3\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$

Therefore what is $438^{87493} \equiv ~?\ (\text {mod}\ 11)$?

> > $$438^{87493} \equiv 438^{87480+13} \equiv 438^{87490} \cdot 438^{13} \equiv 1 \cdot 3 \equiv 3\ (\text {mod}\ 11).$$